# How to integrate multi-languages in a React Native projects

Tags: react-native, module

I want to develop an app in react native, with support to multi-languages like English, Turkish,...
what are you suggest to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize) to add the ability of multiple language support.

You can use [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize) with [I18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) (but also with react-intl, react-i18next, etc. The choice is yours!)

**⚠️ Deprecated:**

We can use an internationalization module named `react-native-i18n` to add many languages in our React Native projects.

Install the following module to link with your project.

```
npm i react-native-i18n --save
```

For more details, please go through [How to add localization (i18n, g11n) and RTL support to a React Native project](https://medium.com/@danielsternlicht/adding-localization-i18n-g11n-to-a-react-native-project-with-rtl-support-223f39a8e6f2).

Answer (score 4):

Recently react-native-i18n has been **deprecated** in favor of [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize).

If you use react-native-i18n, migrating to react-native-localize with i18n-js is really easy.

Here is a post where you can read if you want to migrate from react-native-i18n or implement the new react-native-localize.

[Click here](https://medium.com/@nicolas.kovacs/react-native-localize-and-i18n-js-117f09428017)

**Good coding!**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `react-native-languages`, For more details kindly follow this link:`https://github.com/react-community/react-native-languages`, It's core is i18n-js, so you can get all the necessary methods.