# I need to creat a multi language chatbot in react native with dialogFlow

Tags: react-native, dialogflow-es

I need to put the multilanguage support in my chatBot.

here some code and link of tutorial that I followed.

https://blog.jscrambler.com/build-a-chatbot-with-dialogflow-and-react-native/

Here, is especified --> Dialogflow_V2.LANG_ENGLISH_US,
But i need the multilanguage...

```
 componentDidMount() {
  Dialogflow_V2.setConfiguration(
    dialogflowConfig.client_email,
    dialogflowConfig.private_key,
    Dialogflow_V2.LANG_ENGLISH_US,
    dialogflowConfig.project_id
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set the language in your configuration: that you can set your own language suport in chatbot:



 componentDidMount() {
  Dialogflow_V2.setConfiguration(
   dialogflowConfig.client_email,
   dialogflowConfig.private_key,
   Dialogflow_V2**.LANG_ENGLISH_US,**
   dialogflowConfig.project_id
 );
}
```

> LANG_CHINESE_CHINA
>
> LANG_CHINESE_HONGKONG
>
> LANG_CHINESE_TAIWAN
>
> LANG_DUTCH
>
> LANG_ENGLISH
>
> LANG_ENGLISH_GB
>
> LANG_ENGLISH_US
>
> LANG_FRENCH
>
> LANG_GERMAN
>
> LANG_ITALIAN
>
> LANG_JAPANESE
>
> LANG_KOREAN
>
> LANG_PORTUGUESE
>
> LANG_PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL
>
> LANG_RUSSIAN
>
> LANG_SPANISH
>
> LANG_UKRAINIAN

Answer (score 1):

Use [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize) to add the ability of multiple language support.

You can use [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize) with [I18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) (but also with react-intl, react-i18next, etc. The choice is yours!)

⚠️ Deprecated:

We can use an internationalization module named react-native-i18n to add many languages in our React Native projects.

Install the following module to link with your project.

npm i react-native-i18n --save

For more details, please go through [How to add localization (i18n, g11n) and RTL support to a React Native project.](https://medium.com/@danielsternlicht/adding-localization-i18n-g11n-to-a-react-native-project-with-rtl-support-223f39a8e6f2)

[reference by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789527/how-to-integrate-multi-languages-in-a-react-native-projects)

Comment: Nice answer, but was not it what i need to suport multiply languages in my chatbot... but this help me a lot to support to give many options to other languages insidethe app